# Azure App Service: Login Failed for user - Connection String on ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have a project which is deployed and running, same with the database but here is the problem:

The project has a log-in view. Whenever I try to log in (user and password are correct) I get this exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SqlException: Login failed for user 'projectadmin'.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)

'Projectadmin' is the user for the database and I believe this is all because I haven't found the way to add the connection string to my project.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and I validated that the password is correct under the configuration tab on this menu (it was outdated):

[image]

- How can I update this change on Azure? I just tried republishing the
  project and all collapsed now.
- The connection string has to go on the *.csproj file?

Any other advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, I assumed that you have created the .NET Core 2.0 web application with the individual user accounts authentication. I have checked [your web app](https://plataformafantasypark.azurewebsites.net) and found the `Invalid login attempt` would be returned when the username or password is invalid, so I assumed that you could successfully access your sql database.

> 'Projectadmin' is the user for the database and I believe this is all because I haven't found the way to add the connection string to my project.

You could configure the connection string under the `appsettings.json` file as follows:

```html
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication4;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

When publishing your web application, you could specify the production connection string as follows to override the connection string under the `appsettings.json` for development.

[image]

Moreover, you could also specify your production connection string on azure portal, details you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2016/08/10/working-with-azure-app-services-application-settings-and-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core/).

Additionally, you could leverage SSMS to check the connection for your sql database. And [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) to narrow this issue.